# IDE for PHP/JS/HTML/CSS on UBUNTU with SVN support

Tags: svn, ubuntu, ide, text-editor

I used the search, and the specific topic has not been covered before to the best of my knowledge.

What I'm looking for is an text editor/IDE for Ubuntu (or Linux generally, I know how to compile), to be used in Web Development and that has built in (or extendable via plugins)  support for Subversion. The java based Netbeans / Eclipse IDEs are too heavy.

Tested:

- Geany
- Gedit
- Sublime 2
- Eclipse
- Netbeans

I really like Geany and Sublime 2 as the basic editors when not working on version controlled projects, but the lack of SVN is hurting otherwise since I don't really like to hop into command line or to an another app to commit, update, diff and resolve conflicts.

Eclipse and Netbeans work somewhat, and I'm currently stuck with the latter, but it just seems so engineered as opposed to designed, and is awfully laggy once you have a lot apps running simultaneously (Java, pfff), particularly so when there are a lot of projects its scanning for changes and **big** files.. On top of that, every time I come back to work on the morning, it has crashed or gotten locked up during the night.

I'm open for suggestions, please share your insights, fellow linux web devs :)

Untested due lack of features:

- Bluefish

Comment: mmmm Sublime 2 :) I'm fairly sure you could boot strap an svn commit, update, etc as phony "build" scripts

Comment: I looked into that, but it's not just commit and update one needs to use, but looking at diff and resolving conflicts. :)

That said, it could pretty well be worth it for personal projects.

Comment: eclipse PHP Development Tools, aka PDT doesn't do it for you?
http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

I prefer Eclipse since most other IDEs seem to have issues with memory leaks and lots of files like you mentioned.  An SSD goes a long way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated into Netbeans 7.1 and must say it's working noticeably faster than the older versions or Eclipse. The GUI has been polished a bit too.

On top of the update, disabling Task scanning (TODOs etc.), forbidding Netbeans to scan sshfs mounted remote drives, disabling redundant plugins, and installing http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand have made the IDE feel very snappy, even on this slow laptop I'm using at work.

I'm quite content using Netbeans for now, thus closing the question. I'll update back later if I happend to wander upon something even better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use SVN-boosted editors, but I use SmartGIT as my SVN IDE. It's perfect for us, and it really works. I don't actually even like to have embedded SVN in an editor, as the implementation are normally very wavy.

If you don't have GIT-repo, you can also use the SmartSVN they have. Both of them are free programs.

GIT: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html
SVN: https://www.smartsvn.com/

Comment: Will check it out, even though I explicitly am looking for a solution with integration. Netbeans' SVN integration is great imo, but the app itself is so heavy.

Answer (score 1):

I've always preferred gedit with SVN etc plugins. It's lightweight, and easy to customize.